# Proxy setting for jmeter not working properly

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to set up proxy in firefox so that I can use recoding controller from Jmeter GUI. Below is my network settings in firefox:

[image]
and also the jmeter GUI:

But when I try to load my site in firefox, I am getting the following error:[image]

The owner of app.example.net has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

Learn more…

Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious sites

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a JMeter problem, this is a technique of protection against [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks called [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com/2017/03/understanding-http-strict-transport.html)

You can try to bypass it by

1. Remove entry for your `app.example.net` from the `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt` file in the [Firefox Profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox) folder
2. Add the next `Integer` value at `about:config` page:

   ```
   test.currentTimeOffsetSeconds= 11491200
   ```
3. Clear your browsing history or start with the new Firefox profile

---

Be aware that there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), you will not have to worry about proxies and certificates, just execute your scenario in the browser and once done you will be able to export it as a JMeter test script.